# git rebase -i a branch onto itself

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

I had the following in my repo

```
Master---
     \
       Next-->Commit A.1,Commit A.2,Commit A.3 --......
```

I want to fix-up the A.* commits into one commit describing the feature A.
I tried `git rebase -i origin next`, but that didn't work how I expected.
Is there any way of accomplishing this?

I thought of creating a branch foo, which is essentially next, and then rebase next onto foo followed by merge/delete foo. However, this seems sloppy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
git rebase -i <COMMIT-ISH>
```

... where `<COMMIT-ISH>` is some way of referring to the commit marked `Master` in your diagram.  If there's a branch pointing to that point (probably `master` or `origin/master`) then `git log --decorate` will show that.

Comment: a shortcut: 
    git rebase -i HEAD~10
where 10 is number of how many commit back from the HEAD

Comment: I just went to the initial commit using git log